# How would I pass parameter and check it in mybatis dynamic query creation

Tags: ibatis, mybatis

I have written a select query inside my `mapper.xml`

```xml
<select id="getCatCount" parameterType="String" resultType="int">
    select count(*) from Categories where status is not null  
    <if test="catTypeId != 0">
    AND cat_type_id = #{catTypeId,jdbcType=INTEGER}
    </if>  
</select>
```

and in mapper.java method is

```java
int getCatCount(int catTypeId);
```

How can I check for catTypeId in if condition. I know the above statement is incorrect but I want to put condition like this so I check if catTypeId not zero then only add AND condition. Or do I need to pass whole object of Category class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to pass the whole Category class. Just do it as you described:

```
int getCatCount(int catTypeId);
```

Your mapper.xml should look like this:

```
<select id="getCatCount" parameterClass="map" resultType="int">
  select count(*) from Categories where status is not null  
   <if test="param1 != 0">
     AND cat_type_id = #{param1,jdbcType=INTEGER}
   </if>  
</select>
```

Notice that as `parameterClass` you need to specify a map.

Let's say that now, you want to pass two parameters:

```
int getCatCount(int catTypeId, int mySecondParam);
```

In the mapper, you should work with `param1` and `param2`

See, how you need to use "paramX" nomenclature. But let's say, that instead using that nomenclature, you would like to use a customized parameter name as "catTypeId". For that, in you Java code you need to do this:

```
int getCatCount( @Param("cat_type_id ") String cat_type_id);
```

The XML mapper would be the one that I put it about, but using `cat_type_id` instead `param1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jddsantaella for one more time and for very good explaination.

Comment: This really helped me understand a new api quirk

Comment: Could it be parameter name specified in XML (not with @Param annotation in code)?

Comment: Can the parameter be inherited from parent query to child one. Assume I have resultMap which has its own main query. On top of that I have a collection inside this resultMap which has its own select statement. Can I access the @Param("cat_type_id ") passed into parent call from the child SQL statement in mapper? My initial tests are saying it is not possible.

Comment: beware the `parameterClass="map"` solution only works with ibatis not mybatis